# Sending additional data along with Auth DTO in ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, mono, servicestack

I have an API for web services, Android apps, etc., using ServiceStack. I currently authenticate with a username/password combo that looks something like this on the client side:

```
var authResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Auth {
provider = "credentials",
UserName = user.user_id,
Password = user.password,
RememberMe = true
});
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
var authResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Auth {
provider = "credentials",
UserName = user.user_id,
Password = user.password,
ClientCode = user.clientCode <=====
RememberMe = true
});
```

At this point I need to send a client code along with the username/password. On the other end I will be using that client code to determine which database I should authenticate against.

Since it doesn't seem to be possible to extend the Auth class at this point in time, I'm wondering if there is a more simple place to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use different authentication provider implementation for this. Here are more details:

- Create a separate class for each of your client code like:

```
public class Code1AuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {

        public Code1AuthProvider ()
        {
            this.Provider = "Code1";

        }
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
        }
        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary authInfo)
        {
        }
}
```

Same way create separate classes for each code.

- Now you need to register all your providers in your project's AppHost file.
- Now you can access `/Auth/Code1` as your authentication. Since you are using separate databases, it will be easier to manage code this way.
- use `[Authenticate("Code1")]` where you want the service to be authenticated for a specific type of user.
- At client side you can use appropriate `/Auth/ClientCode` url to authenticate.

Comment: This sounds great as long of he doesn't have too many client codes to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing a header value for the client code. You can search for examples that pass API keys.